# Converting GMT Time to Epoch script

Tags: linux, shell, unix, unix-timestamp

I am currently trying to convert a GMT time into Unix Epoch time. The overall script reads in a CSV file, which has a time stamp, converts it and then appends the Epoch time to the end of the line as a new variable.

I looked a number of posts and read the web page on DATE http://www.linuxmanpages.com/man1/date.1.php and would have assumed that this would work.

```
#!/bin/bash 
OLDIFS=$IFS 
IFS=","
cat test.csv | while read Host AName Resource MName TimeStamp Integer_Value; 
do 

Epoch=date -d "$TimeStamp" +%s

echo "Host: $Host, Name: $AName, Resource: $Resourse, MName: $MName, TimeStamp: $TimeStamp, Integer_Value: $Integer_Value, Epoch: $Epoch";



done
```

When this is run though the script it says that the -d command isn't found I was wondering if someone would be able to help me as to why this might be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To store the value of a command into a variable, use the `var=$(command)` syntax. In your case:

```
Epoch=$(date -d "$TimeStamp" +%s)
```

Also, your `cat file | while read...` syntax could be simplified to a `while do ... done < file`:

```
IFS="," while read Host AName Resource MName TimeStamp Integer_Value; 
do 
...
done < test.csv
```

Comment: Hi Fedorqui Thank you for your answer that helped perfectly and I understood it. I was hoping you would be able to take a quick look at,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21116795/unexpect-new-line-when-write-out-in-unix-shell-script

Answer (score 2):

You have to write

```
Epoch=`date -d "$TimeStamp" +%s`
```

or

```
Epoch=$(date -d "$TimeStamp" +%s)
```